# Automatic Gain Control click & pop bursts

Tags: c++, signal-processing, core-audio

This is my Automatic Gain Control Method, it works but I get a quick burst on the first impulse. How can I scale it down so it doesn't go past 0dbfs? Also the rate at 1e-4 somewhat works but it's too slow.

```
double AGC(double x)
{
double ref = pow(10.0, (-18.0/10.0); //-18dBFS Convert to Linear
double rate = 1.0; // coefficient when increasing/decreasing gain

x = x * m_Gain; //scale input(x)

m_Gain += (ref - (fabs(x) * fabs(x))) * rate;

return x;
}
```

Comment: Myself, I don't know how it works. It may be my ignorance of course. But adding comments and explanations to the code would help many future visitors.

Comment: Yeah, me either. Is it the first sample that's popping? The first n samples? If so can you just drop them (a hack, I recognize).

Comment: @cocell have you figured it out?